# Godot: Instances of the same scene share one instance (instead of being separate)

Tags: godot

I have multiple enemies that all have a sub-scene `detection.tscn` on them. This is an `Area2D` with a `CircleSphere`. I am setting the `radius` of the `CircleSphere` for each enemy individually through code.

However this is where the problem is. When I load the scene, the `radius` is the same for all enemies (it's always equal to the `radius` of the enemy that is the lowest in the scene hierarchy). I have deduced the problem to be that the `detection.tscn` is shared by all the enemies. If I enable `EditableChildren` on `detection.tscn` then the problem disappears (the `radius` is different for each enemy). The instances are separate in this case (which is what I want).

But ideally I want them to be separate without having to enable `EditableChildren`. If I recall correctly then this behavior (that the scenes all share one instance) is actually the wanted (default) behavior. I also think that there is an easy fix for my issue, I just don't remember what exactly it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it's enough to set "local to scene" to the resource (CollisionShape is a resource) to be able to change it separately.
It's normal behavior for resources in Godot.

[image: Where to click]

Comment: did not work, the scene instances still share the same script. I'm not sure how modifying the collider would affect the script anyhow.